# Zero Sized Reply Error - Squid did not receive any data for this request

Tags: http, jboss

I have an application running in JBoss 4.2.3, which is being used for many clients at the same time.

Some of my clients requested support regarding this error:

```
Zero Sized Reply
Squid did not receive any data for this request
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?
Is this happening in another layer, suppose the network layer.
I think this is not even reaching the Application Server layer.

This error only happens in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that spring to mind.

Firstly, can you try using a different browser?

Have you tried emptying your cache/cookies?

Reading through your post, it strikes me that it could be that, coz they'd be different, if you use a different account.